# Should the model in an iOS app contain the information about the API it is used to sync with?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am building a game in which I have two API's that help me to show the leaderboard. The first API gives the overall leaderboard, the top 10 users in the game at any time. The second API gives my position in the leaderboard with five users above me and five users below me. I need to show two tabs in the app which give the overall leaderboard and my position in the leaderboard. I have created a User model in my Core data stack that is used to sync data from the API's. I need to somehow differentiate that which API sent the data that was saved in my persistent store. I would be using this information to delete the previous data that I fetched from the API's so that there is no junk data in my app. Is it ok to save a field in my user model that gives information about which API was used to sync that data? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you would be using this information for?

Comment: @kcstricks I have edited the question description to include more details.

Comment: How are you currently ensuring that you keep both tabs in sync?

Comment: Right now I am saving the data and executing proper fetch requests to get top 10 users and my relative position among the users.

Comment: Why not just wipe out (replace) locally stored data whenever you do a fetch?

Comment: The app needs to work in offline mode as well. These API's are called separately when the user goes to the particular tab. If we the wipe all the locally stored data each time the data fetched from the previous API will also be removed and app won't show any data in the offline mode for that tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting question you didn't ask was 'should I have a unique identifier for users and have only a single representation of the user in the app at any one time' - this is actually a key piece of information...

If you're downloading the 2 different 'types' of data separately and potentially at very different times then you should have multiple representations of any one user in your app, because they could have very different scores at the time of the request/response. It's also appropriate to store a 'flag' indicating the purpose of the data in the system. Note that this isn't the API that the data came from, it's what the data means to the app - what it's used for. In reality, depending on the API design, that might be the same thing, but it's an important conceptual difference.